# Is it possible, through FileSystemWatcher or something else, to be able to retrieve only the new entries of a text/log file that is being watched?

Tags: c#, .net, console, streamreader, filesystemwatcher

I have a folder where I am watching though `FileSystemWatcher` the contents of any log file, i.e. watching `*.log` within a particular directory. I'm now realizing that `FileSystemWatcher` is rather limited and will only be able to kick off events based off changes, however it doesn't return nor know of what changes were made. Is there a library that can control this somewhere or something else I should be using?

When I detect the changes to this DNS Log, I want to get the new entries that were added to the end of the file. I can't even get line numbers from `StreamReader` which I thought might of helped. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.Read whole file on each change and each time compare new lines with previous ones.This would be overkill if the file is too large. If your file is changed by appending text to the end only, then you can Read the file for first time, then you can keep the line count, and in every change you can Skip previous lines and get new ones.And update the counter.For example:

```
private static int counter;
private static string[] currentLines;
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("myfile.txt");
    watcher.Changed += fileChanged;
    currentLines = File.ReadLines("myFile.txt").ToArray();
    counter = currentLines.Length;
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void fileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
     var temp = File.ReadLines("myFile.txt").Skip(counter).ToArray();
     if (temp.Any())
     {
         currentLines = temp;
         counter += temp.Length;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right solution is to employ the filesystem filter driver and intercept file write operations thus getting the data being written right after (or even before) they reach the file.

You can write a filesystem driver yourself (this is quite tricky) or use our [CallbackFilter](https://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) library which includes a ready-to-use driver.

Also if the file is not opened when you detect the change or is opened in the mode that allows reading, you can read the known data from it as Selman22 described in his answer. Note, that it's a bad idea to read text lines - instead you need to read the written data as binary (and read only the data after the position that you have remembered during previous read) and split it to lines in your code.